# Greub, Multilinear Algebra, Notation

Tags: notation, tensor-products, multilinear-algebra

Does any one know what he means with $\tilde E = \otimes_\alpha E_\alpha$ and $\tilde F = \otimes_\beta F_\beta$ ? That is on pages 14 and 15.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an error in Greub's book. Those should be direct sums over the families, not tensor products. He's intending to construct the tensor product of two direct sums.

[This](https://github.com/blargoner/math-algebra-greub-errata) errata listing may be helpful to you.

Comment: Perfect!, that makes sese now. Thanks a lot for this answer, though the question is to some extent old, and there was twindle mssing over the 1st $E$ in $\pi_\alpha: E \rightarrow E_\alpha$